# How to write query to retrieve all columns and distinct for one column?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, spreadsheetgear

Here I am using `c#` code for retrieving the data from the database to spreadsheet when I am writing the query (`SqlCommand`) to retrieve all columns and distinct for one column it's showing error that

> Cannot set Column 'date' to be null. Please use DBNull instead.

Here is my query :

```
  select distinct on columnname *
  from tablename
```

Where I am missing can anyone help me?

Comment: Please show your complete code where you are trying to get the data and [format your code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly.

Comment: Please write your query here

Comment: what else is happening to give this error?

Comment: Hi can you check my code once i  edited my question

Comment: if any one have idea about the above code please help me why it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working back the other way (an Excel Table range => C#) we found that the SpreadsheetGear loads the row of a table array into the header information of DataTable. We couldn't read the cell contents in the first row as table data. To get around this we leave the first row of a table extracted from a spreadsheet as blank then start extracting data from the second row and below.

Perhaps your problem is the reverse of this issue - DataTable (and the SpreadsheetGear API) want you to fill the first row with column heading information and then populate data in subsequent rows.